# Does my JVM have a memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm attempting to assess the efficiency of the garbage collector on one of my servers.

Server OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64

2CPU 16GB RAM

java version "1.7.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

-Xms2560M -Xmx2560M

30 minutes after starting the JVM with no user activity whatsoever (test server) - I see the heap usage slowly but consistently growing over time.

["Heap Usage After GC" graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8HJC.jpg)

```
# jstat -gccause 20630 1s
S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC
0.00  46.88   1.99  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88   8.11  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  14.08  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  20.18  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  26.15  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  32.24  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  38.19  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  44.26  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  50.23  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  56.30  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  62.26  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  68.32  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  74.27  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  80.36  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  84.33  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  90.40  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
0.00  46.88  96.36  30.33  88.16    195    5.393     3    1.468    6.861 Allocation Failure   No GC
46.88   0.00   4.09  30.34  88.16    196    5.418     3    1.468    6.886 Allocation Failure   No GC
46.88   0.00  10.07  30.34  88.16    196    5.418     3    1.468    6.886 Allocation Failure   No GC
46.88   0.00  16.19  30.34  88.16    196    5.418     3    1.468    6.886 Allocation Failure   No GC
```

Wondering if this is cause for concern or if any other information is needed to assist with an answer.

Comment: The garbage collector works. Most likely your program has leaks. You'll want to generate memory dumps and look at them to identify the cause.

Comment: PS. the Java 8 memory management is better, with no PermGen category.

Comment: Well, you *requested* the JVM to allocate 2560MB by specifying `-Xms2560M`. So don’t be surprised that there is no attempt of freeing memory when the currently used heap is as low as 500MB. That doesn’t imply that this used heap consist of all-reachable objects. Maybe a gc would free most of it, who knows. But the JVM respects your request of not doing a gc until reaching about five times that heap usage.